# Convexity of a multivariate function in a region.

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a multivariate function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

In order to check its convexity in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ domain, we can check whether its Hessian is semidefinite positive:
$$
\mathbf{z}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{z}^T \geq 0 \quad \forall \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

But I al only interested in a given region. For instance, I want to check convexity for reals between 0 and 1. How should I adapt the above equation?

My guess is that I should check it for $\mathbf{z}$ that are in that region of interest, but I don't find any reference confirming that.

***For instance***, I have 
$$
f(x, y) = (1-x)(1-y)
$$
[image: 3-D plot]

whose Hessian is:
$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 1 \\
    1      & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And then:
$$
\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{H} \mathbf{z} = 2z_1z_2 \geq 0 \quad \forall z_1, z_2 \in [0,1]
$$

Thus, I would say that this function is convex. But I'm confused because, in the plot, I rather see that it is convex in some directions and concave in others.

Comment: Did you look at my solution at all?
I gave you necessary and sufficient condition.

the $z$'s are directions, and they have nothing to do with points on Domain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your region must be convex. So taking into account a convex region is given. if  region is open then you have same criteria .

in general, even your region is not open, (say $C$ is your region) then you must have $$\mathbf{z}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{z}^T \geq 0 \quad \forall \mathbf{z} \in \text{aff(C)-aff(C)}$$

For those who have problem with $aff$
:  equivalently let $x_0$ be arbitrary point in $C$ then above condition can be equivalently written as $$\mathbf{z}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{z}^T \geq 0 \quad \forall \mathbf{z} \in \text{Span}(C-x_0)$$

Comment: what does the $aff(C) - aff(C)$ mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull   @alberto